# Как собрать свой Linux дистрибутив с grub?

Tags: linux, ос, grub, iso-образ, loader

Я хотел собрать 'минимальную' сборку линукса [по туториалу](https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/702570/), но есть одна проблема - получается на выходе файл .img, а мне нужен .iso (конвертеры что на винде, что на убунту делают небутабельные исошники). Потом хотел собрать grub, из которого бы я сделал iso и который бы загружал саму систему уже из исходников образа, но не нашёл хороших гайдов как 'слепить' груб с системой. Как можно это реализовать? Заранее спасибо.